# Create a list of each element after an iteration of list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list `y=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]` and say (for the illustration of the problem) that I want to add 1 to each element, but still keeping it in the same format, ending up with `yp1=[[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]`.

If I do

```py
yp1 = [val+1 for lists in [num for num in y] for val in lists]
```

I just got `yp1` as a flattened list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add 1 to every element of a matrix / nested list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769581/how-to-add-1-to-every-element-of-a-matrix-nested-list-in-python)

Comment: No, it is not about that but about the comprehension syntax

Comment: Well the first answer is answering that... It's basically identical to your accepted answer so I would say that it is answering your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding of list comprehension is needed here and it also depends on where you put the square brackets

```
y=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]]

yb1=[[j+1 for j in i] for i in y]

print(yb1)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: I even tried that, but forgot to switch some of the variables when I switced the brackets.. thanks!

Comment: @CutePoison Happens sometimes.